# ASP.NET Core MVC build failed error when no other project in Visual Studio solution

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am experiencing a build failed error in ASP.NET Core MVC, even though there are no other projects (which I read that can be the issue but it's not) in the Visual Studio solution.

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core MVC project in Visual Studio, but I am encountering a build failed error even though there are no other projects in the solution. I have checked all the references and dependencies, and they seem to be correct.

I expected the project to build successfully since there are no other projects in the solution. However, I keep getting the build failed error. I am getting error when running entity frame work commands in the console, this is .NET 5 and error is when running Entity Framework Core commands are run in console

[the error and the command run before it can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrJ71.png)

Comment: Can you share the error? This will help us track down where things might be misconfigured.

Comment: Could you upload a minimal example that could reproduce the error?

Comment: I have added the picture of the error in the post , I hope it helps

Comment: make sure there're no anyother complie errors ,or it will failas you've shown